How long was the sea journey for most of the “second wave” of immigrants to New England?
My great x9 grandfather, Rev Ralph Partridge, had an especially long trip from England to New England.  One source said he was at sea for 22 weeks and still needed four more weeks before arriving at Duxbury.  What  was the typical route at that times?  Would these ships have stopped in other colonies such as the West Indies?  How much food could immigrants bring?

Should a "1635-second-wave" tag really be added?

The travel time of 26 weeks of Rev Ralph Partridge was noted in the journals of John Winthrop on 17 Nov, 1636 (P. 199-200):

Two ships arrived here from London, and one a week before. They were
full of passengers,--men,women, and children. One of them had been
from London twenty-six weeks, and between land and land 18 weeks; (the
other two something less time;)

Some examples show that this would be rather lengthy as these voyages generally went.

The Mayflower was only at sea for 66 days, so a little over 8
weeks, Sept 6, 1620 to November 11, 1620.

The Arbella, flagship of the Winthrop fleet, left 8 Apr 1630,
arrived 12 June, again just over 8 weeks.

Another fleet of ships lead by the James in 1635, had floundered
around a hurricane, but still managed to arrive in the
colonies in just under 12 weeks:

The ship James left King's Road in Bristol on May 23, 1635 with master
John Taylor at the helm. From England to Massachusetts in a fleet of
five ships, the Angel Gabriel, the Elizabeth and Ann (Bess), the Mary
and the Diligence.
On June 3, 1635, the James joined four other ships, and set sail for
the New World with just over 100 passengers as part of a fleet of five
ships, including the families of Richard Mather, Captain John Evered,
John Greene and John Ayer. As they approached New England, a hurricane
struck and they were forced to ride it out just off the coast of
modern-day Hampton, New Hampshire. According to the ship's log and the
journal of Increase Mather, whose father Richard Mather and family
were passengers, the following was recorded;
"At this moment,... their lives were given up for lost; but then, in
an instant of time, God turned the wind about, which carried them from
the rocks of death before their eyes. ...her sails rent in sunder, and
split in pieces, as if they had been rotten ragges..."
They tried to stand down during the storm just outside the Isles of
Shoals, but lost all three anchors, as no canvas or rope would hold,
but on Aug 13, 1635, torn to pieces, and with not one death, all one
hundred plus passengers on the James managed to make it to Boston
Harbor two days later.
The Angel Gabriel was wrecked off the coast of Maine, but the smaller,
faster ships, the Mary, the Bess, and the Diligence outran the storm,
and landed in Newfoundland on August 15, 1635.1



So we can see in these examples with travel times of 8 to 12 weeks that there is quite a bit of variation, but the 18 weeks 'between land and land' noted by Winthrop is definitely on the long end as these voyages of the 'Great Migration' went.

What was the ship doing for the other 8 weeks that's not accounted in the 18 weeks "between land and land"? I'm (perhaps erroneously) assuming the quoted phrase means "from leaving London until arriving in Duxbury(?)".

I wonder if some of those 8 weeks were moored offshore becalmed or waiting for westerly winds in England and, at the other end, within sight of land but following the coast to a desired landing point. For example, they might have sent a small party ashore in a boat to find fresh water before continuing.

@RedGrittyBrick: waiting for easterly winds, surely.

@TonyK. Oops yes.
